# Множественная инициализация AIR DATEPICKER

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, airdatepicker

Использую плагин AIR DATEPICKER
Вот HTML

```
<input class="date" type="text" name="#" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" />
<input class="date" type="text" name="#" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" />
<input class="date" type="text" name="#" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" />
```

Если инициализировать так

```
new AirDatepicker('.date');
```

То календарь будет выпадать только при клике на первый инпут. Вот такое решение тоже не работает

```
$(".date").each(function() {
    new AirDatepicker($(this));
});
```

Как можно инициализировать плагин для всех инпутов с классом date?

Comment: Попробуйте циклом:
`for (let i = 0; i < dateInputs.length; i++) {
    new AirDatepicker(dateInputs[i]);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал без *Jquery*.
Но мне кажется библиотека "кривая". Потому что инициализация происходит какая-то хаотичная и чтобы выглядело нормально, нужно лепить костыли (или я ничего не понимаю)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.date').forEach((element) => {
   new AirDatepicker(element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/air-datepicker@3.0.0/air-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/air-datepicker@3.4.0/air-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input class="date" type="text" name="#" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"/>
<input class="date" type="text" name="#" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"/>
<input class="date" type="text" name="#" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"/>
```

---

На *Jquery* будет так:

```
$(".date").each(function(index, element) {
    new AirDatepicker(element);
});
```